# Why my openpyxl code is slower than my VBA code?

Tags: python, excel, vba, performance, openpyxl

I have an excel file of nearly 95880 rows. I made a VBA function that runs slow, so I tried to code a python script using openpyxl, but it's even slower.
It starts fast, then after 600 rows becomes slower and slower.

The VBA Code is

```
Option Explicit

Function FTE(Assunzione As Date, Cess As Variant, Data)
Dim myDate As Date
Dim EndDate As Date, EndDate2 As Date
Dim check As Integer
EndDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Assunzione, 0)

myDate = #1/1/2022#


If Cess = 0 Then
    Call Check2(Assunzione, Data, myDate, EndDate, check)
    FTE = check
Else:
    EndDate2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Cess, -1)
    Call Check1(Assunzione, Cess, Data, myDate, EndDate, EndDate2, check)
    FTE = check
End If
End Function

Sub Check1(Assunzione, Cess, Data, myDate, EndDate, EndDate2, check)
    Dim Cess1 As Date
    Dim gg_lav As Integer, gg_lav2 As Integer
    Cess1 = Cess.Value
    If Assunzione > Date Then
        check = 0
    Else
        If Month(Assunzione) <= Month(Data) And Year(Assunzione) = 2022 Then
            If Assunzione > myDate Then
                gg_lav = Application.WorksheetFunction.Days(EndDate, Assunzione) + 1
                If gg_lav >= 15 Then
                    If Month(Data) = (Month(EndDate2) + 1) And Year(Cess1) = 2022 Then
                        gg_lav2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Days(Cess1, EndDate2)
                        If gg_lav2 >= 15 Then
                            check = 1
                        Else
                            check = 0
                        End If
                    Else
                        check = 1
                    End If
                Else
                    check = 0
                End If
            Else
                check = 1
            End If
        Else
            check = 1
        End If
    End If
 End Sub

Sub Check2(Assunzione, Data, myDate, EndDate, check)
    Dim gg_lav As Integer
    If Assunzione > Date Then
        check = 0
    Else
        If Month(Assunzione) <= Month(Data) And Year(Assunzione) = 2022 Then
            If Assunzione > myDate Then
                gg_lav = Application.WorksheetFunction.Days(EndDate, Assunzione) + 1
                If gg_lav >= 15 Then
                    check = 1
                Else
                    check = 0
                End If
            Else
                check = 1
            End If
        Else
            check = 1
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

and my openpyxl is:

```
def check1(a,d,c,i):
    if ws.cell(row=i,column=a).value > ws.cell(row=i,column=d).value:
        return 0
    else:
        if ws.cell(row=i,column=a).value.month == ws.cell(row=i,column=d).value.month and ws.cell(row=i,column=a).value.year == 2022:
            EndDate = date(ws.cell(row=i,column=a).value.year, ws.cell(row=i,column=a).value.month,
                                    calendar.monthrange(ws.cell(row=i,column=a).value.year,
                                                        ws.cell(row=i,column=a).value.month)[1])
            gg_lav = (EndDate - datetime.date(ws.cell(row=i,column=a).value)).days
            if gg_lav >= 15:
                EndDate2 = date(ws.cell(row=i,column=c).value.year,ws.cell(row=i,column=c).value.month-1,
                                         calendar.monthrange(ws.cell(row=i,column=c).value.year,
                                                             ws.cell(row=i,column=c).value.month-1)[1])
                if ws.cell(row=i,column=d).value.month == EndDate2.month and ws.cell(row=i,column=c).value.year == 2022:
                    gg_lav2 = (datetime.date(ws.cell(row=i,column=c).value)-EndDate2).days
                    if gg_lav2 >= 15:
                        return 1
                    else:
                        return 0
                else:
                    return 1
            else:
                return 0
        else:
            return 1
        
def check2(a,d,i):
    if ws.cell(row=i,column=a).value > ws.cell(row=i,column=a).value:
        return 0
    else:
        if ws.cell(row=i,column=a).value.month == ws.cell(row=i,column=d).value.month and ws.cell(row=i,column=a).value.year == 2022:
            EndDate = date(ws.cell(row=i,column=a).value.year, ws.cell(row=i,column=a).value.month,
                                    calendar.monthrange(ws.cell(row=i,column=a).value.year,
                                                        ws.cell(row=i,column=a).value.month)[1])
            gg_lav = (EndDate - datetime.date(ws.cell(row=i,column=a).value)).days
            if gg_lav >= 15:
                return 1
            else:
                return 0
        else:
            return 1



wb1 = Workbook()
ws1 = wb1.create_sheet()

for i in range(2,95882):
    if ws.cell(row = i, column = c).value == None:
        ws1.cell(row = i, column = 1, value = check2(a, d, i))
    else:
        ws1.cell(row = i, column = 1, value = check1(a, d, c, i))
```

What am I doing wrong? Should I use another library or I'm making the code uselessy memory consuming?
Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: Not sure if it's the problem, but in `check2()` shouldn't it be: `ws.cell(row=i,column=a).value > ws.cell(row=i,column=d).value` ? It's currently using `column=a` for both.

Comment: FYI calling a worksheet function for something you can do in VBA is typically much slower.  For example  `Days()` can be done with VBA's `DateDiff()`

Comment: @sj95126 yes, that's a mistake. Thanks for noticing it! But I don't think that's the reason of code running so slow...

Comment: Your code is extremely cumbersome and too verbose for use to debug. What you're seeing sounds like the result of looping repeatedly over bigger and bigger lists.

Comment: @CharlieClark Yes, I know it's very cumbersome, but I don't have to share this code with anybody and, thanks God, nobody will have to use it/modify it. 
Using numpy instead of openpyxl made it like 100x faster (well I actually removed useless data, but nonetheless the result was impressive to me).
Anyway, if you have some hint for future projects, I'm open :D

Comment: Not much more than start with the simplest thing are work up from that and ask more specific questions. If you want to put the data back into Excel, then sticking with openpyxl should generally be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I think that the problem was with openpyxl. First I tried to reduce the number of observation, from 95K to almost 5K, but it required two and half hour to complete the task.
So I used numpy and it took 55 seconds. Yeah, that's the difference in processing speed.
Here I post the code:

```
with open('data.csv','r') as f:
    data = list(csv.reader(f,delimiter =';'))

arr = np.array(data)
arr = np.resize(arr,(4797,13))
```

I had to change of course the code in this section:

```
a = 3
d = 0
c = 4


def check1(a,d,c,i):
    if int(arr[i][a]) > int(arr[i][d]):
        return 0
    else:
        za = datetime.fromordinal((int(arr[i][a]) + 693594))
        zd = datetime.fromordinal((int(arr[i][d]) + 693594))
        da = date(za.year, za.month, za.day)
        dd = date(zd.year, zd.month, zd.day)
        if za.month == zd.month and za.year + 1899 == 2022:
            EndDate = date(za.year, za.month,
                                    calendar.monthrange(za.year,
                                                        za.month)[1])
            gg_lav = (EndDate - da).days
            if gg_lav >= 15:
                zc = datetime.fromordinal((int(arr[i][c]) + 693594))
                dc = date(zc.year, zc.month, zc.day)
                EndDate2 = date(zc.year,zc.month-1,
                                         calendar.monthrange(zc.year,
                                                             zc.month-1)[1])
                if zd.month == EndDate2.month and zc.year == 2022:
                    gg_lav2 = (dc-EndDate2).days
                    if gg_lav2 >= 15:
                        return 1
                    else:
                        return 0
                else:
                    return 1
            else:
                return 0
        else:
            return 1
```

I don't report the check2 function

```
fte = np.array(10)

for i in range(1,4797):
    if arr[i][c] == '':
        fte = np.append(fte,check2(a,d,i))
    else:
        fte = np.append(fte,check1(a, d, c, i))
    print(i)
```